# How to call and use a subroutine inside another subroutine in fortran?

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I am doing a program in which the main contains many subroutines and functions. For constructing one of these subroutines of the main (let's say subroutine A) I need to make use of another subroutine (let's say B). My question is, how can I make subroutine A call and use subroutine B? I am a beginner and I have searched a lot but found nothing that I understand clearly...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Example of layout, in one file:

```
module MySubs

contains

subroutine A (..)

end subroutine A

subroutine B (..)

   call subroutine A (..)

end subroutine B

function C (..)

end function C

end module MySubs

program MyProg

  use MySubs

  call A (..)

  X = C (..)

end program MyProg
```

You can also place the module and and main program in different files.  In that case compile the file with the module first.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you put all procedures in a `module` and then `use` the module.

If, as your question suggest make all procedures as internal to your main program, there is no problem in calling them. Just invoke them normally using the `call` statement, or by using the function name with the argument list.